# My image doesn't take the full width of the div

Tags: html, vue.js

here's my code

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 ">
        <div class="row">
            <Navbar class="col-12 card shadow-sm" v-if="!isMobile"></Navbar>
            <div class="col-12" style="background:red">
               <img class=" w-100 " height="334.73" src="/modern-minimalist-interior-with- 
               armchair-empty-white-wall-3d-rendering.jpg" />
           </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

[image]
and it also doesn't work with " position " property it leads to a strange behavior

Comment: Make the wrapping DIV a Flexbox container and set `flex-grow: 1` on the image.

Answer (score 0):

You must make column padding = `0`

user inline style `style="padding:0;"` or bootstrap class `p-0`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 p-0">
        <div class="row">
            <Navbar class="col-12 card shadow-sm p-0" v-if="!isMobile"></Navbar>
            <div class="col-12 p-0" style="background:red">
               <img class=" w-100 " height="334.73" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024x768" />
           </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the element, you can see that bootstrap containers and columns have some padding, while the row have some negative margins.

A solution would be to add the class `gx-0` on the row, which removes the gutter between the columns